# MS Access Database Design

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I am new in MS Access.

I am designing a Database for a HRM.

I have seven table

1. emp_personal_info
2. emp_office_info
3. emp_activity
4. salary
5. increment
6. leave
7. extra

Each table has the same ID and only emp_personal_info's ID has declared as primary key. all the tables are connected as one-to-many relation.

The emp_personal_info table's ID is not taking duplicate value. But all the other IDs of other table ar taking duplicate value. How can I stop this ?

This is Database is somehow serving my purpose, but Is it a good database relation ? Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Generally, don't use just `id`; add a qualifier like employee_id. You could probably combine the salary and increment tables. (Not sure about bank_salary.) Otherwise it looks ok.

Comment: It is normal (and by design) that tables on the n side of 1:n relations will have duplicates in the foreign key. -- But all tables should have a primary key (usually an AutoNumber column in each table).